# Apple Pay and Authorize.net Token Submit Fails

Tags: authorize.net

I am working on getting Apple Pay integrated in my app through Cordova (Phonegap) and have successfully retrieved my Apple Pay token. I followed all the instructions outlined in both Apple Pay and ADN documentation. Generated all required keys and certificates (twice). I already have a working ADN integration using both CIM and AIM, so I know my integration is solid. I can process regular auth-capture transactions no problem.

I am working in the ADN sandbox and have tried switching my account between Live and Test, as well as switching test mode between True and False.

Here is the information I generated just now (redacted and truncated):

## Apple Pay Token

```
eyJ2ZXJz.....2dKdWs9In19
```

## Base 64 Decoded Apple Pay Token

```
{ "data" : "PtFJv.....UNFGg==",
  "header" : { "ephemeralPublicKey" : "MFkwEw.....Baor01w==",
      "publicKeyHash" : "Q1q.....Juk=",
      "transactionId" : "c51.....b4"
    },
  "signature" : "MIAG.....AAAA",
  "version" : "EC_v1"
}
```

## ADN Request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<createTransactionRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
   <merchantAuthentication>
      <name>REDACTED</name>
      <transactionKey>REDACTED</transactionKey>
   </merchantAuthentication>
   <refId>C.....4</refId>
   <transactionRequest>
      <transactionType>authCaptureTransaction</transactionType>
      <amount>5</amount>
      <payment>
         <opaqueData>
            <dataDescriptor>COMMON.APPLE.INAPP.PAYMENT</dataDescriptor>
            <dataValue>eyJ2ZX.....9In19</dataValue>
         </opaqueData>
      </payment>
   </transactionRequest>
</createTransactionRequest>
```

## ADN Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<createTransactionResponse xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <refId>CID2254674</refId>
   <messages>
      <resultCode>Error</resultCode>
      <message>
         <code>E00027</code>
         <text>The transaction was unsuccessful.</text>
      </message>
   </messages>
   <transactionResponse>
      <responseCode>3</responseCode>
      <authCode />
      <avsResultCode>P</avsResultCode>
      <cvvResultCode />
      <cavvResultCode />
      <transId>0</transId>
      <refTransID />
      <transHash>2E.....B72</transHash>
      <testRequest>0</testRequest>
      <accountNumber />
      <accountType />
      <errors>
         <error>
            <errorCode>153</errorCode>
            <errorText>There was an error processing the payment data.</errorText>
         </error>
      </errors>
   </transactionResponse>
</createTransactionResponse>
```

Needless to say, this error response is less than helpful. ANY help would be greatly appreciated. Also posted to ADN community forums.

Comment: See this Auth.net support forum post: https://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/E00027-and-CIM-missing-or-invalid-required-fields/td-p/17186 From what I read it sounds like there are fields configured as required that are not being passed with your request. The change most likely needs to made in your Auth.net config for required fields.

Comment: This issue is almost the same, but not quite. I have set the Content-Length on the request with the same results. As for the required fields, I am referencing official documentation located here: http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#apple-pay-transactions - I will note here that I'm programming in Java and have generated sources off of the ADN schema as well.

Comment: I have validated my XML against the schema and it appears to be valid.